# Difference between compile(), parse(), and render() in mustache.js

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

What is the difference between:

`Mustache.compile()` , 
`Mustache.parse()`, and 
`Mustache.render()`

in the new [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js) version 0.5.0, and perhaps for bonus points you could tell us what the difference between parsing and compiling is in general.

Comment: Read the source, I have, but still, see the difference, I cannot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT**

With an [API change introduced in version 0.8.0](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/CHANGES), the `compile()` method has been integrated into `parse()`. Manually compiling the templates is no longer required.

---

`Mustache.parse()`

Syntactically parses the template and creates a JavaScript function body (*a string*) from it. During that process it notifies of any syntax errors encountered in the template.

`Mustache.compile()`

Uses the function body returned from a successful `parse()` to create an actual JavaScript function. The created function is placed in a cache for re-use.

`Mustache.render()`

Takes the appropriate function for a given template (the one that was created by `compile()`) and applies it to actual data. This creates the result meant to be shown on screen.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak!  I can see how compiling before rendering would make sense sometimes for performance maybe?, but I can't think of a situation where it would make sense to use parse.  Could you give an example where it would?

Comment: @alnafie Parsing is always the first step in transforming an arbitrary string (one that happens to comply with the Moustache syntax) into something a computer can act on. It is exactly what happens to your JavaScript source code files when they are read by the browser. Without parsing the input you give it, no computer can do anything. moustache.js compiles the template into a JavaScript function tailored to do exactly what the template says, and nothing else. In the end this will run a lot faster than interpreting the template every time you call ("render") it.

Comment: Exposing a parse stage also gives something that makes sense to stick in a memcache and use at your front end.

Answer (score 3):

Just a tip `Mustache.parse(template)` is optional and speeds up future uses of template. This is useful when you want to reuse your template with a set of (large) data. If this is not the case a call to the `Mustache.render()`, which generates the final result, is enough.

Answer (score 2):

A little extra:
If you working with custom delimiters (instead of `{{` and `}}`), you can use `Mustache.parse` before calling the `Mustache.render` with the custom delimiters as a parameter.

Example:

```
var template = "<h1>Hello {{$name$}}</h1>"
var customTags = [ '{{$', '$}}' ];
Mustache.parse(template, cutomTags);
var result = Mustache.render(template, { name: "John" };
console.log(result);
```

Will result In:

```
Hello John
```